# Why Erlang functions are not memoized by default?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, memoization

One of the properties of [functional languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) is that functions do not have side effects, thus the same input should always yield the same output. It seems that those languages could easily and heavily benefit from [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

But, at least regarding [Erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_(programming_language)), there is no default memoization of the functions' calls. Is there any particular reason that Erlang (and other functional languages as far as I know) do memoize by default (or with a simple trigger), or at least have explicit, good support of memoization?

*Is there something inherently wrong with memoization?*

One reason I can imagine is that with memoization your memory footprint can grow quickly. Right, but Erlang already runs on VM and manages memory, so I guess it could tame caches and prevent them from growing quite easily.

**Related**:

- [Memoization in Erlang](http://cicale.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/memoization-in-erlang/)
- [How does one use cached data in a functional language such as Erlang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997276/how-does-one-use-cached-data-in-a-functional-language-such-as-erlang)
- [Simple example for Erlang memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313190/simple-example-for-erlang-memoization)

**Edit**:

- [What is an idempotent operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077412/what-is-an-idempotent-operation)
- [Too big too fail](http://joearms.github.io/2013/04/01/too-big-to-fail.html) :)

Comment: Erlang is not side-effect free.  For example, I could write a function that opens a logfile and returns the requested number of bytes from the end of it.  Called twice with the same argument, this function will probably return two different values.  Or consider random:uniform, whose return value cannot be cached.

Comment: Of course, we don't live in no-size-effect utopia. Still, lack of side effects is a cornerstone of FP

Comment: Don't confuse side-effects with idempotentence. "Multiple executions with same input always yield same output" is the definition of idempotence, side-effects obviously does not affect output

Comment: The `too_big_to_fail` flag should of course not be taken seriously... April fools' day ;)

Comment: Holy Byte, they got me. Did anyone tell Motorola and Ericsson? :)

Comment: Is there some stat that shows that there is an interest to do that. My first feeling is that it would be a huge design effort for a small effect. But it is only a feeling, and I am curious to know if there is any study done on a real life application.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of mistaken assumptions in this question.

> One of the properties of functional languages is that functions do not have side effects

Incorrect, only "purely functional languages" have such a constraint. Erlang is not purely functional.
It permits arbitrary side effects in functions.

> Is there any particular reason that Erlang (and other functional languages as far as I know) do memoize by default (or with a simple trigger), or at least have explicit, good support of memoization?

No languages (at least non-toy ones) implement by-default memoization of all function calls. Why? Massive space leaks would ensue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he meant "don't memoize by default"